# How to make derived class function private so that it is not accessible by base class pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    public:
    virtual void acctobase() {
        cout <<"base\n";
    }
};


class D: public B
{
    void acctobase() {
        cout <<"derived\n";
    }
};

int main() {

    B* o = new D();
    o->acctobase();//i want this function not to be accessible using derived class object

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried private B::accatobase; but still it is accessible and also i do not want to inherit class B privately so how to change its access specifier ?

Comment: You're abusing the type system. What's your real problem?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If you don't want to override the method, then don't declare it as an override!  (i.e. give it a different name/signature, or remove "virtual" from the base class)

Comment: Reminds me of the patient coming to the doctor saying "It hurts when I twist my arm like this...", and the doctor replying "Then don't twist your arm like that." - presumably you have a REAL problem that you are trying to solve, so describe that, not your "I think this will solve the problem" [I have a feeling I know what that solution is, but I'm only guessing to what you are actually trying to solve]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, by design.

Derived class must always be compatible with its base, in the sense that whatever functions you can call on a base class should be callable on all of its derived classes. This is what [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is about. That is why you can make member functions from base class more accessible in a derived class, but you cannot make it less accessible.

Comment: I'm totally on board with Liskov, but that is not actually what C++ enforces.  Meaning, you can use C++ to implement a bunch of stuff that Liskov says you shouldn't ever do, so one must be extra careful and go way beyond "Can I make this stuff compile" to satisfy Liskov.  I wish I weren't speaking from experience!

Comment: @JohnZwinck You are absolutely right about inability to enforce LSP at the level of the language: I think an attempt to do that would necessarily lead to the language becoming more restrictive than it should, greatly reducing flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the method in the derived class to `throw std::logic_error();`.  Then any caller will receive an error at runtime.  After all, you're doing something which fundamentally requires a runtime type check anyway--you can't know in general at compile time if the method should be accessible or not, so you can only make it "inaccessible" (unusable) at runtime.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: hey, not only that, it's even a bad idea!  But it is, I think, the closest one can come to what the OP asked for.  Here's hoping once the OP sees this "solution" he/she will find a better way.  :)